# How to get the subkey from the key in the registry tree using NSIS?

Tags: nsis

From the below registry tree structure, how to get and show the the subkey (3.1.0) from the below path:

SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\APE\PowerChart\

```
HKLM
    SOFTWARE
        APE
            PowerChart
                3.1.0
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Look at my answer, EnumRegKey, not  EnumRegValue.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using normal 32-bit NSIS you can just enumerate the subkeys if you don't know which exact version you are looking for:

```
Section
StrCpy $0 0
loop:
  EnumRegKey $1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\APE\PowerChart" $0
  StrCmp $1 "" done
  IntOp $0 $0 + 1
  MessageBox mb_ok "Key: $1"
  Goto loop
done:
SectionEnd
```